# How do I add these dot spacers as seen in the photo?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to add spacers in between my titles like the ones between the words Remote and Full-time or the ones between Full-time and Entry level.

Comment: can you show some HTML and CSS to see what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use CSS to style a dot character as a spacer.

```css
.title:not(.last)::after {
  
  content: "\2022";
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.title {
  
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Remote</div>
<div class="title">Full-time</div>
<div class="title last">Entry Level</div>
```

This will add a dot character after each title, with a small space in between. You can adjust the spacing by changing the `margin-left` value. You can also customize the appearance of the dot by changing the `font-size` and `color` properties.

Comment: I think that `&centerdot;` (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B7) looks more like the example image. `&bull;` is too large

Comment: yeah it does...